# How to override the default login for Django rest framework browsable API

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, okta

I have a Django Rest Framework (DRF) application and when we are using the browseable API page and click login it goes to the default Django login page. I want to override it to another page.

Default api:
`https://my-app/api-auth/login/` 
But the new login page I want is this:
`http://my-app/signin/` 
the auth is done by Okta in the application.

I did try overriding this

`LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/signin/' LOGIN_URL = '/signin/'`

Answer (score 1):

```
from rest_framework import authentication

class CustomAuthentication(authentication.BasicAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        # perform custom authentication logic here
        # ...
        # return a tuple of (user, auth) or None if authentication fails
        return None
```

#### Then you will need to add this authentication class to the DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES in the REST_FRAMEWORK setting in your settings.py file

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'path.to.CustomAuthentication',
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you @parth, but  will this change the default login from /api-auth/login/ to /myapp/signin/

Comment: The code I provided in my previous response will change the way that authentication is performed for the views or viewsets you have specified it for, but it will not change the default login URL from /api-auth/login/ to /myapp/signin/.